# How to configure Let's encrypt for a server with openvpn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, openvpn

I want to make my Rails app SSL available, but I failed to configure it.

I'm using `Let's encrypt` for SSL and the server is using `Nginx`. There is also `openvpn` service that is installed by [openvpn-install](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install).

This is what I done for installing:

```
$ sudo service openvpnas stop
$ sudo service openvpn stop
$ sudo service nginx stop

$sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d ganan-finance.com
/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cryptography/__init__.py:26: DeprecationWarning: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of cryptography will drop support for Python 2.6
  DeprecationWarning
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Cert not yet due for renewal

You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry.
(ref: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/ganan-finance.com.conf)

What would you like to do?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: Keep the existing certificate for now
2: Renew & replace the cert (limit ~5 per 7 days)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 2
Renewing an existing certificate
/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/acme/jose/jwa.py:110: DeprecationWarning: signer and verifier have been deprecated. Please use sign and verify instead.
  signer = key.signer(self.padding, self.hash)
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for ganan-finance.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/ganan-finance.com/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/ganan-finance.com/privkey.pem
   Your cert will expire on 2018-02-16. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot-auto
   again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
   "certbot-auto renew"
 - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:

   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
$ sudo service openvpnas start
$ sudo service openvpn start
$ sudo service nginx start
```

#### Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ganan-finance.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ganan-finance.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ganan-finance.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

And [Why No Padlock](https://www.whynopadlock.com) shows this error:

```
SSL verification issue (Possibly mis-matched URL or bad intermediate cert.). Details:
ERROR: certificate common name 'tk2-207-13319.vs.sakura.ne.jp' doesn't match requested host name 'ganan-finance.com'.


    Certificate valid through: Jun 30 20:40:44 2025 GMT
Certificate Issuer: 
SSL Protocols Supported: TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
```

And I used [openvpn-install](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install) to install `openvpn`.

I think the problem is caused by mixing up `openvpn` and `Let's encrypt` configuration. But I couldn't figure out how to solve the problem.

What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: The Certbot Nginx plugin takes care of re-configuring Nginx : see [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Certbot auto reconfiguration just replace `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` that is already there with same values.